# JQuery check if Table Cell is NOT Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML table and some cells will be empty, I can find the empty cells and replace the the value, but I want to know how to check if the cell HAS a value and if so then make the change

So far, I can do change all cells, or just change the empty cell, but I want to know how to make a change if a cell is **not** empty.

[The Fiddle code is found here](http://jsfiddle.net/SimonPrice/n67wkxb2/2/)

```
            <table id="SearchTable" class="table table-striped" style="text-align: justify">
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                    Report Detail
                </th>
                <th>
                    Form
                </th>
                <th>
                    Attachments
                </th>
                <th>
                    Result
                </th>
                <th>
                    Report No.
                </th>
                <th>
                    Report Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Form No.
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="text-align:center">
                <td class="reportManager">

                </td>
                <td class="reportDetail">
                    <span style="opacity: 0.349019607843137; font-size: 40px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></span>
                </td>
                 <td class="form">
                    <span style="opacity: 0.349019607843137; font-size: 40px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></span>
                </td>
                <td class="attachments">
                    <span style="opacity: 0.349019607843137; font-size: 40px;"><i class="fa fa-paperclip">
                    </i></span>
                </td>
                <td class="result">
                    Success
                </td>
                <td class="reportNo">
                    Rpt-001001110
                </td>
                <td class="Date">
                    08-09-2012
                </td>
                <td class="formNo">
                    A000146647
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>


$("#SearchTable").find("td.reportManager:not(:empty)").html('<span style="opacity: 0.349019607843137; font-size: 40px;"><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i></span>')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `:empty`, use `:not(:empty)` to find the cells that aren't empty:

```
$("#test").find("td.def:not(:empty)").html('<strong>not empty<strong/>')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n67wkxb2/3/)**

Comment: I was just trying that, looked up from JQuery API and wasnt working, tried yours and it worked.  I can and will accept the answer in 8 minutes when stack lets me

Comment: the example in fiddle works, however when i use this in my app its bringing through the new value regardless of being empty or not

Comment: Then you'll need to post a code example that replicates the issue.

Comment: But in your revised example the cell `td.reportManager` *is* empty.

Comment: if its empty it shoudnt give anything, if its not empty it should give me the fontawesome as per the javascript in fiddle. but, empty or not it still returns a value when it should and should not

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. What does `give me the fontawesome` mean?

Comment: fontawesome is an icon set, which is what i am looking to replace the cell value with. However, I completely scrapped my code and re-written it and got it working using your original javascript. So once again, I thank you